# git-bash.exe and bash.exe show different compiler version and paths

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, git-bash

When I start `git-bash.exe` by, for example, selecting "Git Bash Here" option and check my compiler version and path I receive the following output:

```
$ g++ --version
g++.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ which g++
/mingw64/bin/g++
```

But if I run `sh.exe` or `bash.exe` from shell even with `--login -i` options I get this:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 9.1.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ which g++
/usr/bin/g++
```

I thought `--login -i` options should load the same environment as `git-bash.exe`.

**Question**

Is it possible to make them load the same environment?

**Edit1**

I use `git-sdk-64`. It is installed in `C:\git-sdk-64`.

`git-bash.exe` is located in `C:\git-sdk-64\git-bash.exe`.

`bash.exe` and `sh.exe` are both located in `C:\git-sdk-64\usr\bin\`

- `C:\git-sdk-64\usr\bin\bash.exe`
- `C:\git-sdk-64\usr\bin\sh.exe`

I do not have `cygwin`.

**Edit2**

`ldd` output for `g++`:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/g++
        ntdll.dll => /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffea4a50000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffea3ac0000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffea2780000)
        msys-iconv-2.dll => /usr/bin/msys-iconv-2.dll (0x5603f0000)
        msys-2.0.dll => /usr/bin/msys-2.0.dll (0x180040000)
        msys-intl-8.dll => /usr/bin/msys-intl-8.dll (0x17cc50000)

$ ldd /mingw64/bin/g++
        ntdll.dll => /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffea4a50000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffea3ac0000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffea2780000)
        msvcrt.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ffea3ca0000)
        libwinpthread-1.dll => /mingw64/bin/libwinpthread-1.dll (0x64940000)
```

Comment: If it's Windows 10, `bash.exe` starts the default WSL distribution, IIRC.

Comment: @Ramhound is it possible to set command line parameters/flags to the bash.exe in order for it to load mingw64 environment?

Answer (score 0):

They are typically from different environments : MSYS for the first one and Cygwin (I guess) for the second one.

They may even interpret directories differently. Cygwin has `/` synonymous of a `C:\cygwin` directory. This makes the environment closer to a Unix system, but quite different from MSYS.

A `mount` command could confirm or infirm the Cygwin environment which typically declares (at least) :

```
D:/Cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
D: on /cygdrive/d type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

A `ldd /usr/bin/g++` should show the used DLLs (at least on Cygwin) and indicates how `g++` is compiled.

Comment: I am not sure if I even have cygwin installed on my system (I don't remember installing it, also checked that there is no C:\cygwin folder). I included some more info in the question, which I believe relates to your answer.

Comment: Just try the `ldd /usr/bin/g++` and the `mount` commands and show us what is displayed.

Comment: Added ldd for /usr/bin/g++ and /mingw64/bin/g++. They are the same for both git-bash.exe and bash.exe

Comment: I was right about 2 different environments, but one is MSYS and the other MINGW64. Note that on MSYS (in a similar way as Cugwin), `/` is not the root of the C: drive, but typically `C:/msys64` as the mount command show. Then a given file could be named differently in the two different environments. Curiously, on my PC, a bash command in git-bash environment doesn't seem to switch anything.

Comment: @a_girl - You have mingw64, which is practically identical to that of Cygwin

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer on my PC when I start git-bash.exe and then type bash it doesn't change anything either. I just wonder if it is at all possible to load mingw64 env into bash.